# How do I log the actual SOAP requests in XML format

Tags: xml, soap, asp.net-core-mvc, event-log, envelope

In VS2019, I've added a connected service and configured it to point to a SOAP service. Using .NET Core how to log the exact XML which is being sent to the SOAP from Reference.cs class.

We need to log the complete xml format with SOAP envelop in .NET core. I will be grateful to hear any ideas.

Thank you

Comment: What client class are you using?  The class is performing a XML Serialization and you want to capture the XML.  I do not know what code you are using so I can't answer the question.